# Reporting Services and custom assembly connecting to third party web service

Tags: web-services, reporting-services

I have the following problem. I am using Reporting Services 2005 to create some report. I call method from my custom assembly and it works fine when my method is as follows:

```
public static string TestMethod() {
return "test"; }
```

However, when return "test"; is replaced by the code that calls third party web service, there is nothing returned to my RS report. I can't even log my exception to EventLog (probably because of security reasons). 
I  class is decorated by the following statement:

```
[System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Level = System.Web.AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted)]
```

additionally, for the purpose of calling web service I've added the following in my custom assembly:

```
string serviceUri = "http://externallink/Default.asmx";
                WebPermission p = new WebPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept, serviceUri);
p.Assert();
```

This does not help either. The error that is thrown in my custom assembly is as follows:

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Net.WebPermission, System,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed

Can someone can please help me?

EDIT1:
I figured out that reporting services uses custom trust level called: RosettaSrv. Custom policy is set in rssrvpolicy.config. When I changed trust level to Full, everything works fine. However I don't want to specify full trust, just possibility to access custom web services, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create your specific CodeGroup section in the CAS policy config file (as you mentioned) for RS, which  tells it to grant that permission for your assembly.

Follow steps found in this MSDN article for details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842419